# Html to Xml rendering error in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml

***Input html string :***

```
htmlstring = "<a href="main.aspx">main&reg;</a>";
```

I am getting exception when convert the html string to xml document using folowing code

**code:**

```
XElement onDemandLink = XElement.Parse(htmlstring.ToHtmlString());
```

**Exception Message :**

```
Reference to undeclared entity 'reg'.
```

can anyone help me to convert this?

Comment: If this is plain HTML (as opposed to XHTML), then it's not necessarily valid XML - you'd be better off using something like the HTML Agility Pack to parse that.

Comment: I agree with @CharlesMager  .... this specific problem you report is due to the fact that the contents of the <a> contain data that is not escaped to the XML convention, causing the error. Since this is not valid XML as-is, but it seems to be valid HTML syntax, you should consider using a parser that works with HTML

Comment: If you are facing this problem only on **&reg;** then replace that entity reference with its equivalent unicode numbers **&#174;**

Comment: @codeninja.sj : Thanks for your help. Using your approach it solved the problem . But this like hardcode right. But I need global fix.

Comment: `htmlstring.Replace("&reg;", "&#174;");` using this code it solved the problem but i need to replace all character

Comment: Finally found the solution :using HttpUtility.HtmlEncode and Decode solve the problem  **Thanks All**

Answer (score 0):

**Use HttpUtility.Encode and convert to xml element**

```
htmlstring = HttpUtility.HtmlEncode("<a href="main.aspx">main&reg;</a>");
XElement onDemandLink = XElement.Parse(htmlstring.ToHtmlString());
```

Comment: That would replace `&reg;` with `&amp;reg'` instead of `&#174;`. Also it would replace `<` with `&lt;` and so on.